# Not sure how DbContext is creating SQL query to wrong table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework but im trying to model my code after some examples I have found online. I thought I had it set up the way I wanted but the Query that is created is pointing to the the wrong, non-existant table. I am wondering where it got the table name because it is wrong and I am not seeing any where in any of the project files that this wrong table name was specified. Here is the query that was generated and I got from debugging:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[AssetTag] AS [AssetTag], 
[Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], 
[Extent1].[PoolType] AS [PoolType], 
[Extent1].[InventoryStatus] AS [InventoryStatus], 
[Extent1].[InventoryType] AS [InventoryType], 
[Extent1].[Comments] AS [Comments]
FROM [dbo].[ComputerInventories] AS [Extent1]}
```

ComputerInventories should be ComputerInventory.

Here is my data model

```
public class ComputerInventory
    {
        [Key]
        public String AssetTag {get; set;}
        public String Location { get; set; }
        public String PoolType { get; set; }
        //public String ReasonInProgram { get; set; }
        public String InventoryStatus { get; set; }
        public String InventoryType { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500)]
        public String Comments { get; set; }
        //public String Clock { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ComputerInventory> ComputerInventory { get; set; }

        public AssetDBContext()
            : base("Name=<name>")
        {
        }
    }
```

Here here is where the I am trying to get the list from the query

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.ComputerInventory.ToList());
        }
```

I am completely lost as to where it is getting the ComputerInventories value for the table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework uses naming conventions for many things.  One of them is that table names are created by taking the plural of the entity name.  You can remove that convention like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

See [PluralizalingTableNameConvention on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

For more information on conventions

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions

Comment: That worked, thank you. And Thank you for the additional information

Answer (score 3):

Although this has been answered already, I would just like to add an alternative for any future visitors to this question...

Rather than removing the convention, simply specify the table's name by overriding the same method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Object>().ToTable("TableName");
}
```